# Resizing image view in Portrait mode and landscape mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

Can anyone tell me about the way to resize my image view to show images in both portrait and landscape mode .i want to show them full screen .Please help

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: are you using interface builder or doing it by code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

and also set leftmargin ,right margin from above code

Comment: also can u tell me how can i write a code for the event ,i.e clicking return in the keyboard when i type anything in my text box

Comment: @Christina: I suggest you ask a new question to get response on it.

Comment: Ask new question..I am not getting what you want to ask

Answer (score 2):

hey change the frame of the image view in the didOrientationChange method..Simple as that...!!